# Need a button on notification tray

Tags: c#, winforms, system-tray

I am working on desktop application.

I developed code for notification tray in desktop application.

here is my code for design view..

```
partial class Form1
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.notifyIcon1.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon1.Icon")));
        this.notifyIcon1.Text = "notifyIcon1";
        this.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        this.notifyIcon1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick);
        this.notifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick);
    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;
}
```

And below code for notification content.

```
notifyIcon1.Visible = true;  
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Hello notification";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = Dl.name;
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(4000);
```

I want to show button on this notification and also I want handle than button click.

Is it possible with desktop application?

Comment: Have you ***ever*** seen a button in the notification tray? Me either. Thinking about it, isn't the icon itself very much like a button? What's the difference?

Comment: Hello spender , thank you for your replay.  yes notification tray is itself button. Actually i want to add more than one button at notification tray that's why i asked question. If you have solution for this please tell me. -

Comment: The conventional way to deal with this is to have the icon spawn a menu "on-click" and to place your "buttons" (menu choices) in the menu. Otherwise, consider multiple icons (a bit of an abuse IMO).

Comment: That is right. I have to spawn a menu "on-click" and to place your "buttons" (menu choices) in the menu. It would be very appreciate if you have any link or example in which i get this code After all, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Google NotifyIcon MSDN : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?view=netframework-4.7.2